# Some specific hyperlinks in website not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am working on a website and it has a couple of links. When I click on links, nothing happens even though the browser status bar shows the target URL correctly. I checked that there is no z-index or any such issue (still might have missed something).

Here is the link of the site - http://www.deals4all.gr/city.php?ename=athens

Once there, click on "Select City" box and 2 links will be shown. Try clicking on either of them. None works. Moreover when I open the link in new tab or copy paste the link in new window, it works fine. I have checked this issue in IE, FF and Chrome.

Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a JavaScript issue — I noticed your code was obfuscated/packed using Dean Edwards' packer, so I pasted it into http://jsbeautifier.org and quickly found the problem:

```
jQuery('#guides-city-change').click(function () {
    return !jQuery('#guides-city-list').toggle()
});
```

When you click on a link, the click event bubbles up to `#guides-city-change`, firing the above handler.  `toggle()` always returns the jQuery object it was called on, and negating an object with `!` will always evaluate to `false` resulting in `return false`, which will cancel the default action of the `<a>` that the event originally fired on.

Since there is no default action for `<div>` elements, the easiest solution is to use `event.stopPropagation()` instead:

```
jQuery('#guides-city-change').click(function (e) {
    jQuery('#guides-city-list').toggle();
    e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Side note: if you're using the packer for obfuscation purposes then don't bother.  As you can see, it's very easy to work around.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As you mentioned, JS is packed and you also mentioned it's easy to workaround. Could you please throw some light on how to workaround this situation?

Comment: @Vikram: simple, I just pasted your entire packed JS code into the box at http://jsbeautifier.org - it will clean it up by unpacking it and then adding all the lines and indentation back in.

Comment: Oh you meant that. I thought you were referring to something else. Let me try this. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1):

The link works correctly.

The problem is that navigating to

```
http://www.deals4all.gr/city.php?ename=athens
```

takes you back to the home page

Comment: Therefore, in his PHP he hasn't defined what to do once ename=athens. Make sure your using the $_GET function to get it.

Comment: The "Select city" box he's referring to is on the home page too.

Comment: That's not the issue. Everything is being handled properly in PHP and the same code is working flawlessly on other domains. It's most likely the JavaScript issue as mentioned by Andy. Will give it a try and update.